# default value is not displaying before onChange event in dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dropdownlist which is having location list and there is a label tag. By changing dropdownlist item, the currency will display in that label. This function is working fine but initially the label is showing blank. It is displaying after onChange event. How to display currency initially.

Here i did the onChange event.

action Code: (mruCode is the id of the list)

```
export const currencyLists = mruCode =>({
  type: CURRENCY_LIST,
  payload: mruCode
});
```

reducer code:

```
case 'CURRENCY_LIST':
            let newState = Object.assign({}, state)
            let newCurrList = newState.location.filter((el) => el.mruCode === action.payload)
            return Object.assign({}, newState, {
                currList: newCurrList
            });
```

component code:

```
render(){
    const{conLocations}=this.props;
    const _labels = store.getLabels();
      return(<div>
          <span className="btnElement_spacing">Your current location is:</span> 
           <select id="toggleLocationName" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                                {conLocations.map((item,index) =>
                 <option  key={index}  value={item.mruCode}>{item.mruCode}-{_labels[item.division]}-{item.country}</option>
                  )}
        </select> 
        <span className="btnElement_spacing"> in </span>
                <span id="toggle-currency" >
      {this.props.currList.map((item,index)=><span key={index} value={item.mruCode}>{item.currency}</span>)}
                </span>
          </div>
           );
  }
```

List is like : **[{mruCode:"1700", division:"Agricultural",country:"USA",currency:"USD",...},{mruCode:"1000",division:"Agricultural",country:"CANADA",currency:"CAD",...},{mruCode:"1500",division:"Industrial",country:"AUSTRALIA",currency:"AUD",...}]** .

So initial loading while dropdown showing country 'USA' currency should show 'USD'

Comment: Could you try giving 'value' as default prop with "0" as value for 'select' element?

Comment: Will you please elaborate it?  Initial dropdown first item is USA while initial loading... But in span tag currency is blank... If I change any value in dropdown then currency is showing

Comment: Since in the map function u are creating options and not giving anyone as selected, hence there is no default selection.

Comment: Actually dropdownitem is dynamic based on conLocations list as you can see. So,  sometimes it is single item or two items or more...  So is it possible to do that in reducer code or modify it.

Comment: yep in reducer u can do it. U can even do it in the same component. but as far as i understood u need to show the default country and the currency in 2 separate dropdowns. so for that u dont require reducer

Comment: Yes....But, i am filtering out the conLocations list and store the values into currList. So, only if onChange event fires then currency will show up. But, i need currency at initial loading. If initial loading dropdown shows country 'USA' then currency should 'USD' or initial loading dropdown shows country 'CANADA' then currency will show 'CAD' like that. Now, it is happening after onChange event

Comment: I could elaborate more but could you please add a sandbox so we could understand your problem and try to fix it?